# how change mesh and vertex and edges color

Tags: modeling

please help change mesh color for object mode and change edges/vetexes color for edit mode because I do not see vertexes and edges because it is black and edges in blueprint is black too !
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g5zE.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the colors in User Preferences>>Themes>>3D View.
[image]

Comment: thanks it works in 2.8