# Priorities of edge colors in Blender

Tags: edit-mode, edges, uv-image-editor, color

What are the visual priorities of edge colors in blender?
How it decides which color to show when edge is marked with different properties?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific please? What do you mean by edge colors? Do you mean, e.g. when a back light picks out an edge? Or do you mean edge coloring as in the assignment of edge colors to a grid so that no two edge colors have the same color, e.g. in the layout grid?

Comment: I mean when two or more operations are applied on edge, Like Seam, Mean Crease and Sharp, Which color would be shown in priority wise? And What is reason for that?

Answer (score 3):

The priority is following:

1. UV Seam - **Red**
2. Bevel Weight - **Blue**
3. Edge Crease - **Purple**
4. Sharp Edge - **Cyan**
5. Freestyle Edge - **Green**

[image]

*Note: Default colors in Blender 2.82*

Comment: Perhaps this is useful as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141861/how-change-mesh-and-vertex-and-edges-color